# Is it a valid approach to create a channel to a gRPC server within the same application?

Tags: c#, websocket, protocol-buffers, grpc

To give you a little bit of context.

I implemented a gRPC server inside my C# application so clients are able to trigger some commands like hiding and showing the app.

This should also be possible with a javascript client inside a browser.

So my first idea was to use the gRPC implementation for web clients but it is only working with a proxy to be able to talk to my c# server.

To make things a little bit easier I implemented a WebSocket server as well and send the protobuf bytes back and forth.

This is working great and there's only one missing piece.

How could I use the current implementation with gRPC with my WebSocket server?

My idea was to connect to the gRPC server with a gRPC client inside the same application, so the WebSocket server is a client of the gRPC server.

For that, I added a new Protobuf message that contains all possible messages and is only used for WebSocket communications.

```
message Payload {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp = 1;
    oneof data {
        ApplicationWindowRequest request = 2;
        ApplicationWindowResponse response = 3;
    }
}
```

Now I am able to parse the binary data from the js client back to the Payload object and send the request to the gRPC server through the gRPC client.

```
private void OnBinary(IWebSocketConnection socket, byte[] message)
{
    var payload = Payload.Parser.ParseFrom(message);

    commonClient.ChangeVisibility(payload.Request);
}
```

Is this a valid approach because I found no solution to call some services directly on the server itself?

Comment: A Http Server is always the same.  There is no difference if the Http Server is inside your application or is started as a service.

Comment: That's true. But is it performance wise a good idea? Maybe it is no big deal because grpc is aimed for performance between microservices. And in my case, the microservices are inside my app.

Comment: There should be no difference in performance unless the Service is setup to run with higher priority.